# gradle version manager tool for windows like pik for ruby

Tags: gradle, pik

Like `pik` which provides the facility to switch between ruby versions on the fly from command prompt, is there any tool which provides the same kind of behavior for gradle, so that i can switch to gradle version I'm using based on need.

I googled it, but couldn't find proper solution. So posting here.

Below error I'm getting when use sdkman windows version:

```
PS C:\Users\user> Import-Module posh-gvm
This command is not available in offline mode.
At C:\Users\user\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\posh-gvm\Utils.ps1:294 char:14
+         throw <<<<  'This command is not available in offline mode.'
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (This command is...n offline mode.:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : This command is not available in offline mode.

Import-Module : The specified module 'posh-gvm' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module dir
ectory.
At line:1 char:14
+ Import-Module <<<<  posh-gvm
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (posh-gvm:String) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
```

Comment: Your gvm issue should really be a separate question. Pointing to sdkman/gvm answers your original question.

Comment: see if this helps: https://github.com/flofreud/posh-gvm/issues/13

Comment: @RaGe yeah.. thanks for the link.. that gvm issue because Windows Powershell version 2.x  installed in my machine as mentioned in the link. I can't upgrade to 3.x as its my office laptop. Anyways, i'm marking the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there's such tool. It's called [sdkman](http://sdkman.io/). You can easily switch between versions of gradle, groovy and other available frameworks, languages.

Comment: Hi, i 've gone through that. But i don't see straightforward approach for windows. Getting several errors when i use "powershell" version for windows users. Updated question with the error.

Comment: Not a windows user, can't help you :/

Comment: that gvm issue because Windows Powershell version 2.x installed in my machine as mentioned here : github.com/flofreud/posh-gvm/issues/13. But I can't upgrade to 3.x as its my office laptop. It will work for the users who can install Powershell 3.x or above. So, i'm marking the answer as accepted.